# MySQL trigger on insert of text going into infinite loop

Tags: mysql, loops, triggers

There are three tables: users, ap_name_bank_m and ap_name_bank_h. users table has three columns 'name_eng' (name of user in english), 'name_gdn_eng'(name of user's guardian in english) and 'category'.

ap_name_bank_m and ap_name_bank_h are corpus of names for each category of name: 'm' or 'h'.

When a row is updated I want to check if each word of both names in present in either of two tables ap_name_bank_m and ap_name_bank_h.

Whichever count is higher that category will be assigned. The below code which I have written is going into infnite loop and I am getting "MySQL server has gone away error". Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

Assume name_eng and name_gdn_eng will only contain words with spaces and nothing else.

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger set_cat before update on users_table for each row
BEGIN
declare words text;
declare word varchar(50);
declare num_m int default 0;
declare num_h int default 0;
declare len int default 0;

set words = concat(new.name_eng,' ',new.name_gdn_eng);

iterator:
LOOP
set word = substring_index(words,' ',1);
set num_m = EXISTS(select 1 from ap_name_bank_m where name=word) + num_m;
set num_h = EXISTS(select 1 from ap_name_bank_h where name=word) + num_h;

set words = trim(replace(words,word,''));
END LOOP iterator;

if (num_m > num_h) then set new.category='M'; end if;
if (num_h > num_m) then set new.category='H'; end if;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why should the loop terminate

Comment: @P.Salmon Got it. So how to remove the words from loop?

Comment: exit loop when words is empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to do this. No need for loop.

```
BEGIN
declare words text;
declare word varchar(50);
declare num_m int default 0;
declare num_h int default 0;

set words = concat(new.name_eng,' ',new.name_gdn_eng);

set num_h = (select count(*) from ap_name_bank_h where match(name) against (words in natural language mode));

set num_m = (select count(*) from ap_name_bank_m where match(name) against(words in natural language mode));

/*
iterator:
LOOP
set word = substring_index(words,' ',1);
set num_m = EXISTS(select 1 from ap_name_bank_m where name=word) + num_m;
set num_h = EXISTS(select 1 from ap_name_bank_h where name=word) + num_h;

set words = trim(replace(words,word,''));
END LOOP iterator;*/

if (num_m > num_h) then set new.category='M'; end if;
if (num_h > num_m) then set new.category='H'; end if;
END
```